# C++, printf выводиться не полностью

Tags: c++, массивы, printf

Проблема заключается в том, что первый массив оно вывело, а следующий одномерный и измененный двумерный оно не захотело, код не останавливает работу, но и ничего не выводит, суть программы "Дан двумерный целочисленный массив. Вставьте в него одномерный массив после всех колонок с парными номерами."

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int const n=4, m=6;
    int a[n][m+m/2]; int i,j,k=0;
    int b[n];
    int jl;
    srand(time(0));
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for (j=0;j<m;j++)
        {
            a[i][j]=-23+rand()%35;
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("\n");
        for (j=0;j<m;j++)
        {
            printf("%4d",a[i][j]);
        }
    }
    cout<<"\n";
    for (i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        b[i]=1+rand()%81;
        printf("%4d",b[i]); //тут не выводит
    }
    for (jl=m-1; jl>=0; j--)
    {
        if(jl%2==0)
        {
        for (i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            for(j=m+k-1; j>=jl+1; j--)
                {
                    a[i][j+1]=a[i][j];
                }
                a[i][jl+1]=b[i];
            }
            k++;
        }
    }
    printf("\n======");
    for (i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("\n");
        for (j=0; j<m+k; j++)
        {
            printf ("%4d", a[i][j]); //и тут не выводит
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ну так инициируете переменную `jl`, а уменьшаете переменную `j` в цикле `for (jl=m-1; jl>=0; j--)`

Answer (score 2):

Вот тут

```
for (i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    b[i]=1+rand()%81;
    printf("%4d",b[i]); //тут не выводит
}
```

Все нормально выводит. А дельше

```
for (jl=m-1; jl>=0; j--)
```

Видите? У вас `jl` не меняется, и всегда равно `m-1`, потому что вы уменьшаете `j`, так что цикл бесконечный.

А если написать

```
for (jl=m-1; jl>=0; jl--)
```

то выводится и всё остальное.